# Responsive changes affecting other sizes

Tags: html, css, web, size, responsive

I started by making the desktop version then went to create the ipad pro version at `1024` pixels.
so I set:

```
@media only screen and (max-width1024px) {
}
```

and started to make my changes. Once the changes were made I went on to creat the iphone version at `375px`

```
@media only screen and (max-width375px) {
}
```

However when I create changes on the `375px` it affects the `1024px` version. Every size is affecting the others with the exception of the original desktop version. I fix one version to my liking, but when I go to work on another version it changes what i previously worked on. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your Media Queries are wrong. Try this way `@media screen and (max-width: 375px) `

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 375px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {}
```